# Parsing time string to seconds

Tags: c#, parsing

I parsed a function from python which converts for ex. "5m" to 300 seconds (integer). My question is about the regex expression I did, because I know it's slow compared to anything else. What is the best way to get the integer part of the `timeframe` and the string part as well into a separate string? Basically, what I did, but efficiently. Not like it really matters in my situation, but I like it to be strict.

```py
def parse_timeframe(timeframe):
    amount = int(timeframe[0:-1])
    unit = timeframe[-1]
    if 'y' == unit:
        scale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
    elif 'M' == unit:
        scale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
    elif 'w' == unit:
        scale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    elif 'd' == unit:
        scale = 60 * 60 * 24
    elif 'h' == unit:
        scale = 60 * 60
    elif 'm' == unit:
        scale = 60
    elif 's' == unit:
        scale = 1
    else:
        raise NotSupported('timeframe unit {} is not supported'.format(unit))
    return amount * scale
```

```cs
public static int ParseTimeFrameToSeconds(this string timeframe)
{
    var amount = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(timeframe, @"\d+").Value);
    var unit = Regex.Match(timeframe, @"[a-zA-Z]+").Value;

    int scale;

    if (unit == "y")
        scale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
    else if (unit == "M")
        scale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
    else if (unit == "w")
        scale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;
    else if (unit == "d")
        scale = 60 * 60 * 24;
    else if (unit == "h")
        scale = 60 * 60;
    else if (unit == "m")
        scale = 60;
    else if (unit == "s")
        scale = 1;
    else
        throw new NotSupportedException($"Timeframe unit {unit} is not supported.");

    return amount * scale;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no need to use [regexes](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) for this. just translate *what the existing python code does*: accessing substrings of your input.

```
var amount    = int.Parse(timeframe.Substring(0, timeframe.Length - 1));
var unit      = timeframe.Substring(timeframe.Length - 1);
```

Comment: Thanks! 
`var amount = int.Parse(timeframe[0..^1]);
var unit = timeframe[^1..];`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you have a proper TimeSpan, you can cast your string to `TimeSpan` and then use the `TotalSeconds` prop.

That will also get rid of all the if-else ifs that you have.

```
if (TimeSpan.TryParse(timeframe, out var timeSpan))
{
   Console.WriteLine(timeSpan.TotalSeconds);
}
```

*Edit: As is, you assume every year is 365, every month is 30 days. Your calculation might be misleading anyway.

Comment: I tried converting "5m" to TimeSpan and it doesnt work out of box.